# Create Feature Class does not have any input fields present?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, geoprocessing-framework, error-000735

I'm using ArcMap10.2 and when tying to create feature classes, empty tool is displayed.

when i click OK "error 000735 :feature class:name is required "is displayed.

[image: screenshot one, the first display after clicking create feature class]

[image: screenshot two:the screen displayed after clicking OK from the above figure]

Comment: I think you should try each of these in turn and only move on to the next one if the problem persists. 1. Restart ArcMap (I'm assuming that you are running this from its Search window) 2. Reboot and then restart ArcMap. 3. Delete/rename the Normal.mxt 4. Uninstall/reinstall ArcGIS for Desktop.

Comment: Before step 4, (step 3.5) locate the "ESRI" hive in the registry under HKEY_CURRENT_USER, Software. Rename it "ESRI_OLD". Restart ArcGIS. See this [forum thread](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=983&t=235461), post oct 15, 2007.